# How to make GridView layout like this?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-gridview

I want to make layout like this?

Is possible with GridView? Problem is that first row must have just one column, and all others  must have two columns per row?

Or is there another way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the top view is the only one to be different, you can add a header to your GridView using a special kind of GridView: [HeaderGridView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/idea133/src/com/android/photos/views/HeaderGridView.java)

Comment: Hm, I didn't know for this. Is there any example?

Comment: You have all the source code of the Google photo app with that link. I guess that's a hell of an example.